# Jmeter Parametrization: Is it possible to parameterize request URL for Post request with body

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

When  I tried to  navigate to  Parameters tab ( to parameterize part  of request url)  , for a http request with body data, I am not able to do it.
I get the following error 
" you cannot switch  because your data cannot be converted to target tab data. Empty data to switch"
I cannot empty the the body as the its required for the post data ?

FYI. the parameterization task is simple, part of url needs to be filled with some random 10 digit number

appreciate the pointers. 
 I am using Jmeter 3.0 
[SEE Screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRWw5.png)

Answer (score 2):

you no need to switch to parameters tab. you can parameterize the part (random 10 digit number) by replacing it with ${10_digit_value} (here, 10_digit_value is picked from CSV Date Set Config under variable names field. refer images)

[image]

CSV file containing values to parameterize and 10_digit_value is column name to refer.

[image]

replace the random 10 digit number with the reference.

You can follow the same approach in case the random number is in Path filed also.

Comment: Thanks Naveen. The problem I am having is  whenever there is any data in the post  body  (Say json ) it  is not allowing me to  change the tabs and prompts the error asking me to empty the  body. Please see screen shots  added to original question

Comment: Yes, because Parameters tab can be used only when you have key value pairs as body such as user=temp&pass=temp etc. so any data not following above format can't be shown in parameters tab. It is not a problem at all. Still you can parameterize in Body section itself as mentioned in the answer. I didn't get why do you want to switch to Parameter tab as you can achieve the task without switching to it and Parameters tab is just to display the data in formatted manner. I hope you got my point. :)

Comment: Thanks Naveen. Yes the data i was trying to  pass was  name=value pair (snapshotid=<somenumber>  Hence thought of using parameter tab. I get  your point and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this by adding a bean shell pre processor that the HTTP request is retained and the URL is parameterized as well. 
This is the command i  used in HTTP request URL 
the request was a  POST request and  had some payload  in json { tags: .... } } 
/some/url/path//aggregate?snapshotId=${tim}

In bean shell pre  processor I had added 
the following

```
import java.lang.System;
String timStr = System.currentTimeMillis().toString();
vars.put("tim", timStr );
```

This replace  part of  url with dynamic value and retained my Json in post request as well.